# CruiseControl failing view compilation with Asp.net MVC 2 RTM

Tags: msbuild, asp.net-mvc-2, cruisecontrol.net, compilation

Tehnologies:
- CruiseControlNet
- Asp.net MVC 2 RTM
- enabled view compilation

The problem is `UrlParameter.Optional` setting. I can't seem to make it work when I use this setting inside a view.

When I compile inside Visual Studio, everything works fine, but when CCNet uses `MSBuild` to compile it it fails with following error:

```
errorCS0103: The name 'UrlParameter' does not exist in the current context
```

pointing to the line inside my view where this parameter is set on:

```
Html.RenderAction(...)
```

that sets certain route parameter(s) to optional.

I tried adding `<%@ Assembly name="System.Web.Mvc" %>` at the top of my view, but it didn't work either. It works of course when I disable view compilation, but that's not really an option. And I also don't want to set my optional parameters to `string.Empty`.

**Anyone has any hint on this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution/Workaround

I checked CCNet configuration of my project and I added the following line in the `<msbuild>` element:

```
<buildArgs>/noconsolelogger /p:Configuration=Release</buildArgs>
```

After that I also changed my csproj file to set these:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    ...
    <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    ...
    <MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This way my views are only being compiled in development, where we compile as Debug, but not by MSBuild on CCnet where it now compiles as Release.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your web.config has in the `<compilation>` section the following entry:

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Comment: It does... That's why it compiles just fine in Visual Studio, but doesn't in CCNet with MSBuild. I guess.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue (actually, that is how I came to find your question/workaround). It turns out our build server had an older version of MVC 2. You need the RC.

HTH.